# plot slightly separated in-group bars with ggplot2 geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom-bar

Is there a way to have a little separation between each group bars made with grouped `bar_plot()`? Like having a bigger distance between different groups and small distance inside group bars, but not sticked one another.

Here the whole code:

```
### my DF generation
df.bar <- as.data.frame( cbind(
                                "diagnosis" = rep( names_DX, 2 ) ,
                                "number" = as.numeric(c(9,18,43,8,34,12,3,7,38,12,8,6)),
                                "status" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
                                ))
df.bar$diagnosis <- factor(df.bar$diagnosis,levels(df.bar$diagnosis)[c(1,5,6,2:4)]) #reorder levels for plot

### plot generation
p <-    ggplot(data = df.bar, aes(x = diagnosis, y = as.numeric(as.character(number)), fill = factor(status) )) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())+
            theme_bw()
```

my result:

[image: sticked bars]

what I'd like to get (ignore colors difference etc, only for the bars positions):

[image: separated bars]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust these with the `width` parameters of `geom_bar` and `position_dodge`.

`geom_bar`'s `width` controls how wide each individual bar is. If `= 1`, the bars will collectively be as wide as the whole x-axis. (Though there may be space between groups if the bars overlap with each group.)

`position_dodge`'s `width` controls how much space each group is given. If it's zero, the bars in each group will be fully overlapped. If it matches the `geom_bar` `width`, the bars in each group will be touching each other on the sides. If it's 1, the distance between groups will be the same as the distance inside each group.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df.bar, aes(x = diagnosis, y = as.numeric(as.character(number)), fill = factor(status) )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",  width = 0.4,
           position=position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]